# how do you search and replace in python

Tags: python

I have a server name that is in unc. I need to remove all text from the firs period to the end of the text.

for example,

```
server='web01.dc1.example.com'
```

I need this to be:

```
server="web01"
```

I tried this:

```
import re

server=re.replace("*.+","",server)
```

any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
server='web01.dc1.example.com'
re.sub(r"\..*$","",server)
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `regex` , use `str.split()` :

```
>>> server=server.split('.')[0]
>>> server
'web01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
>>> server='web01.dc1.example.com'
>>> server[0:server.index('.')]
'web01'
```